# Does PyMySQL support Prepared Statements?

Tags: python, pymysql

Does PyMySQL support prepared statements?
I am trying to connect to MySQL from a python module.

I have checked documentation at http://pymysql.readthedocs.io and didn't find anything useful.

No luck on skimming the source code either.

Answer (score 4):

PyMySQL does not support prepared statements yet. See [PyMySQL issue 202](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/202)

Answer (score 0):

No support for Prepared Statements will ever come to PyMySQL, I guess. Use Oracle's MySQL Connector for this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html